# How to forward virtual host to other server?

Tags: server, virtualhost

I have two web servers at home and one external IP. Local IPs on servers is 192.168.1.10 (main server) and 192.168.1.11. On my router I forwarded all 80 and 443 traffic to main server but on my second server I have one website(domain.com in folder /var/www/domain). What I have to write in virtual host's config file on my main server to forward traffics for domain.com to second server?

Comment: Actually, on the main server, you need to create a virtual host that works as reverse proxy for a virtual host of the second server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to forward and route trafic only on your router. I dont know any other way. Since you have only one official IP you either have to serve all http trafic on one server, or you use another port for the second server.

Comment: I created a new rule on my router to forward port 8080 to my second server. Also changed Listen port to 8080 in ports.conf of apache2. Now everything is working. Only one problem: to reach domain on server 2 i need to type http://domain.com:8080. Is it possible on server one redirect all traffics coming to this domain from port 80 to port 8080?